# create dynamic frame with schema from catalog table

Tags: python, boto3, boto, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have created table in catalog table through create_table in API aws glue.

Through this code sample below code is creating table in catalog.

When I create dynamic frame from this table, it is empty with no schema.

I want to create empty dynamic frame with these four columns

```
response = client.create_table(

      DatabaseName= 'xxxxxxxxxx',
      TableInput={'Name':'xxxxxxxxxx',
        'StorageDescriptor': {
        'Columns': [
            {'Name': 'column_1', 'Type': 'string', 'Comment': 'None'},
            {'Name': 'column_2', 'Type': 'string', 'Comment': 'None'},
            {'Name': 'column_2', 'Type': 'string', 'Comment': 'None'},
            {'Name': 'column_2', 'Type': 'string', 'Comment': 'None'}
        ],
        'Location':'s3://xxxxxxx/',
        'InputFormat': 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat',
        'OutputFormat': 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat',
        'SerdeInfo': {
            'Name': 'avro',
            'SerializationLibrary': 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe',
            'Parameters':'{"type":"record","name":"DynamicRecord","namespace":"root","fields":[{"name":"column_1","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"column_2","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"column_3","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"column_4","type":["string","null"]}]}'
        }
```

}}
    )

Comment: What do you mean connection? through API or what? is that boto or boto3?

Comment: Don't want to run the crawler for the same

Answer (score 0):

> A DynamicFrame is similar to a DataFrame, except that each record is
>   self-describing, so no schema is required initially. Instead, AWS Glue
>   computes a schema on-the-fly when required, and explicitly encodes
>   schema inconsistencies using a choice (or union) type. You can resolve
>   these inconsistencies to make your datasets compatible with data
>   stores that require a fixed schema.

Link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-schema

You may use `apply_mapping()` to set schema explicitly or need some data in s3 location.

Comment: Is there any way we, change create_table function, such that it would return dataframe or dynamic frame with schema.

Comment: currenty it is giving ++
||
++
++

Comment: I define it explicitly, in the columns parameter above